# Does adding too many application listeners affect performance?

Tags: java, spring

Is there any limit for the number of ApplicationListernes in Spring application?

How do they affect performance?

Is it better to create less application listeners to operate event aggregates?

Comment: No so long as the method for ApplicationListener isn't doing anything slower than constant speed, you won't have a big effect on performance

Comment: Basically it depends on what your application listener is doing

Comment: You could just have one Listener per kind of Listener(ActionListener, MouseMotionListener,...) and decide within it what to do(e.g. evt.getSource or alike), but in the end the amount of "work" the Listener has to do is what determines the speed-impact of a Listener.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, but you have to take into account that putting code in a Listener is going to give you a cleaner code but it still being Single Threaded(unless you make it otherwise), so it won't be faster either to put stuff in a Listeners.

Listeners are a very good decoupling strategy.